# boost::asio : data corruption

Tags: c++, boost-asio

I present a simple client and server written in **Asio** to show something that might be a bug.
client repeatedly sends a fixed string of length 102 to the server and server checks the string
to be correct and writes an error message if not so and exits.

The code is compiled and run in debian 7 (amd64)
my processor has 2 cores
boost version is 1.55

when running server and client, after a few thousand packets are sent
a wrong packet is received.(it may be required to repeat the test a few times)

what is the problem?

**Makefile**

```
CXX=g++
LIBS = -lboost_thread -lboost_filesystem -lboost_system

all: server asyncclient
server: server.o
    $(CXX) $(LIBS) server.o -o server
asyncclient: asyncclient.o
    $(CXX) $(LIBS) asyncclient.o -o asyncclient
server.o: server.cpp
    $(CXX) -c server.cpp
asyncclient.o: asyncclient.cpp
    $(CXX) -c asyncclient.cpp
```

**server.cpp**

```
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/bind.hpp>
#include <boost/thread.hpp>
using boost::asio::ip::tcp;
char teststr[]="1234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890\n";
void session(tcp::socket* sock)
{
    boost::array<char, 102> buf;// 102 == sizeof(teststr)
    int i=0;
    try
    {
            for (;;)
            {
                    std::cout<<i++<<std::endl;
                    boost::system::error_code error;
                    size_t length = boost::asio::read(*sock, boost::asio::buffer(buf), error);
                    if (error == boost::asio::error::eof)
                            break; // Connection closed cleanly by peer.
                    else if (error)
                            throw boost::system::system_error(error); // Some other error.
                    if(strcmp(buf.data(), teststr)!=0)
                    {
                            std::cerr<<"error"<<std::endl;
                            std::cerr<<"    buf.data() = "<<
                                    std::string(buf.data(), buf.size())<<std::endl;
                            return;
                    }
            }
    }
    catch (std::exception& e)
    {
            std::cerr << "Exception: " << e.what() << "\n";
    }
}

int main()
{
    std::cerr<<"sizeof(teststr) = "<<sizeof(teststr)<<std::endl;//DEBUG
    boost::asio::io_service ios;
    tcp::acceptor a(ios, tcp::endpoint(tcp::v4(), 41000));
    tcp::socket sock(ios);
    a.accept(sock);
    boost::thread t(boost::bind(session, &sock));
    t.join();
}
```

**asyncclient.cpp**

```
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/bind.hpp>
#include <boost/thread.hpp>

using boost::asio::ip::tcp;

char teststr[]="1234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890\n";

void handle_write(size_t num_bytes, boost::system::error_code e)
{
    static int i=0;
    if(!e)
    {
        std::cout<<i++<<std::endl;
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout<<"Error: "<<e.message()<<std::endl;
        exit(1);
    }
}

int main()
{
    boost::asio::io_service ios;

    tcp::resolver r(ios);
    tcp::resolver::query q(tcp::v4(), "127.0.0.1", "41000");
    tcp::resolver::iterator it = r.resolve(q);

    tcp::socket sock(ios);
    boost::asio::connect(sock, it);

    boost::thread t(boost::bind(&boost::asio::io_service::run,&ios));
    try
    {
        for(;;)
        {
            boost::asio::async_write(sock, boost::asio::buffer(teststr,102),
                    boost::bind(&handle_write,
                    boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred,
                    boost::asio::placeholders::error));
        }
    }
    catch(std::exception& e)
    {
        std::cout<<"Exception: "<<e.what()<<std::endl;
    }
    t.join();
}
```

Comment: christopher kohlhoff solved the problem for me: "This operation is implemented in terms of zero or more calls to the
stream's async_write_some function, and is known as a composed
operation. The program must ensure that the stream performs no other
write operations (such as async_write, the stream's async_write_some
function, or any other composed operations that perform writes) until
this operation completes."

From:
<http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/async_write/overload1.html>

Comment: Could you post that as an answer? I didn't notice it and wasted some time to reproduce it. What was the symptom of failing anyway?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the problem comes from the following for loop:

```
for(;;)
    {
        boost::asio::async_write(sock, boost::asio::buffer(teststr,102),
                boost::bind(&handle_write,
                boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred,
                boost::asio::placeholders::error));
    }
```

an async_write operation may be begin before the completion
of previous async_write which is not allowed.
**REF:** [async_write](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/async_write/overload1.html)

the correct way is to eliminate the for loop and call async_write 
in the handle_write function:

```
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/bind.hpp>
#include <boost/thread.hpp>

using boost::asio::ip::tcp;

char teststr[]="1234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890\n";

void handle_write(tcp::socket* sock, size_t num_bytes, boost::system::error_code e)
{
    static int i=0;
    if(!e)
    {
        std::cout<<i++<<std::endl;
        boost::asio::async_write(*sock, boost::asio::buffer(teststr,102),
                boost::bind(&handle_write, sock,
                    boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred,
                    boost::asio::placeholders::error));
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout<<"Error: "<<e.message()<<std::endl;
        exit(1);
    }
}

int main()
{
    boost::asio::io_service ios;

    tcp::resolver r(ios);
    tcp::resolver::query q(tcp::v4(), "127.0.0.1", "41000");
    tcp::resolver::iterator it = r.resolve(q);

    tcp::socket sock(ios);
    boost::asio::connect(sock, it);

    boost::thread t(boost::bind(&boost::asio::io_service::run,&ios));
    boost::asio::async_write(sock, boost::asio::buffer(teststr,102),
            boost::bind(&handle_write, &sock,
                boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred,
                boost::asio::placeholders::error));
    t.join();
}
```